# How to create a switch/case statement with div id as the case parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a dropdown list that will show different results based on the dropdown selected. Here's my minimal example for reproduction:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("dropdown");
elem.onchange = function(){
  if /*this is where I'm stuck. And on the following code. I want to say if the dropdown id = 1, 
  then show div option1_result*/
    let hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("option1_result");
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none":"block";
};
```

```html
<p>
Please select the dropdown:
</p>
<select id = "dropdown">
  <option id = "1" class = "selected"> option 1</option>
  <option id = "2" class = "selected"> option 2</option>
</select>

<div class = "result">
  <div class = "option1_result" style="display:none;">
    <p>
      Option 1 Result! 
      <button href="#">
      See More
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class = "option2_result" style = "display:none;">
    <p>
      Option 2 result
      <button href="#">
      More about opt 2
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I'd like to do this where

```
case (1):
  hiddenDiv.style.display = "block";
```

But I'm not sure that will work in this instance.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexisrambles/z9dc0uw1/10/)

Comment: `let hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("option" + /* the id of the selected option */ + "_result")`. Then just check for `null` before changing the `style`

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't just using `value` as it is the standard parameter for `option`?

Comment: @imvain2 I had values in my original code but had no idea what they did or how to select them so I figured better take them out?

Comment: @AlexisRichard `value` is the proper way to handle that as it is the standard parameter for a select and ID is meant for each element and not the options.

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks for the heads up! I'll definitely remove those IDs then and replace with value = "1" etc. 
This why self-teaching coding is hard. I tend to miss things like that. Best practices and all.

Comment: @Andreas OH! That sort of concatenation is what I was looking for but didn't exactly know how to describe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Jacob's answer, it seems you should also give **id** not **class** to the result options.

> ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to
>   identify more than one

and to clear your options whenever you select other options, in onchange

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].children, (child) => child.style.display = "none")
```

otherwise options would pileup.

Also you can avoid the using if statement in your case. Use **template literals**.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("dropdown");
elem.addEventListener("change", () => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].children, (child) => child.style.display = "none")
  const hiddenDiv = document.getElementById(`option${elem.value}_result`);
  hiddenDiv.style.display = "block"
})
const hiddenDiv = document.getElementById(`option${elem.value}_result`);
  hiddenDiv.style.display = "block"
```

```html
<p>
  Please select the dropdown:
</p>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1" class="selected"> option 1</option>
  <option value="2" class="selected"> option 2</option>
</select>

<div class="result">
  <div id="option1_result" style="display:none;">
    <p>
      Option 1 Result!
      <button href="#">
      See More
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="option2_result" style="display:none;">
    <p>
      Option 2 result
      <button href="#">
      More about opt 2
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH! Template literals are exactly what I was looking for and didn't know to ask for. That's super helpful, thanks so much!

Comment: This does answer my question completely so I marked it as answer. But I do have a further question. Can I still use Template Literals if two dropdown options will give the same result? For example, I'm sorting parishes into regions. Parishes 1, 4, and 7 are all in Region 2.

Comment: Template literals are used to embed easily something into string.It all depends on your logic

Comment: Okay so I wrote everything in, but I keep getting an error saying that I can't access the .style attribute of null. So my assumption is that there's something with const hiddenDiv going on. I'm doing this on jsfiddle-- [link](https://jsfiddle.net/alexisrambles/130bxq9e/92/)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in the implication?

Comment: It should be  document.getElementById(`region{elem.value}_result`) in  template.and also correct the values of options

Comment: I didn't catch the region error... GAH. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The `id` attribute is for uniquely identifying an *element* in the document. It's not intended to convey the *value* of a select option. For that, you want to use the `value` attribute:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1" class="selected">option 1</option>
  <option value="2" class="selected">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Once you have a value for your options, you can check for what the selected value is like this:

```
if (elem.value === '1') {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks. I'm a little fuzzy on when IDs are okay and when you shouldn't use them.

This makes sense! Thanks so much! I'll give it a go.